# Chop out parts of a square matrix in Matlab

Tags: matlab, matrix

Is there an inbuilt function that removes the Kth row and column of a square matrix in Matlab?

Hope it's clear from the diagram:

[alt text http://img121.imageshack.us/img121/8145/cutmatrix.png](http://img121.imageshack.us/img121/8145/cutmatrix.png)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here are two simple solutions:

```
x([1:k-1 k+1:end],[1:k-1 k+1:end])
```

or:

```
x(k,:)=[];x(:,k)=[];
```

Comment: @Ramashalanka - your first line is much more elegant than mine.  I feel silly I didn't see that myself.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to use this operation more often, creating a function is a good idea.

```
% filename: removeK.m

function M1 = removeK (M, k)
  M1 = M([1:k-1 k+1:end],[1:k-1 k+1:end]);
end
```

Answer (score 1):

Not a builtin function, but the following line does the trick:

```
y = [x(1:(k-1),1:(k-1)) x(1:(k-1),(k+1):end) ; x((k+1):end,1:(k-1)) x((k+1):end,(k+1):end)];
```